# Blank underlined line in jsf in h:outputText

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have tried this but got only blank spane without underline

```
    <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline" rendered="#
{declarationBB.deaclarationOpr.declarationDetailsobj.productName == null}" value="                           " />
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure the component is rendering? You should replace `rendered="#
{declarationBB.deaclarationOpr.declarationDetailsobj.productName == null}"` by `rendered="#
{empty declarationBB.deaclarationOpr.declarationDetailsobj.productName}"`

Comment: Which browser are you trying with?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Browser is Internet Explorer and I tried even your code but I get just blank space but no blank line.

Comment: I mean, you're sure that is an styling problem, I suposse you have the same result if you remove the `rendered` attribute?

Comment: As this site references, there can be problems with some old IE versions http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration

Comment: use underscores instead of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonsignificant whitespace in HTML will be collapsed. You effectively end up with no visual representation unless you insert non-whitespace characters in the beginning and the end like so:

```
value="[                           ]"
```

If all you want is a line of a fixed size, rather use a bunch of underscores:

```
__________________________
```

Or, if you really want to use HTML/CSS for this, use a block element of a fixed width and border bottom:

```
<div style="width: 200px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

A `<hr>` is however semantically more correct if all you actually want is a "horizontal rule":

```
<hr style="margin: 0; width: 200px; height: 1px; background: black; border: none;" />
```

Noted should be that you should avoid using `style` as much as possible and use `class`/`styleClass` instead.